# Fix my Graphics vector class, One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

http://codepaste.net/i87t39
The error I get is "One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type"

```
public class Vector3D<T>
{
    public T x; 
    public T y; 
    public T z;
    public Vector3D()
    {
    }
    public Vector3D(T a, T b, T c)
    {
        x = a; y = b; z = c;
    }
    /*public Vector3D(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        x = a; y = b; z = c;
    }*/
    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return base.ToString();
        return String.Format("({0} {1} {2})", x , y , z);
    }
    public Vector3D<double> operator+( Vector3D<double> right)
    {
        Vector3D<double> vd = new Vector3D<double>() { x = 0, y = 0, z = 0};
        vd.x = left.x + right.x;
        vd.y = left.y + right.y;
        vd.z = left.z + right.z;
        return vd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I copy the code in your link:

```
public class Vector3D<T>
{
    public T x; 
    public T y; 
    public T z;
    public Vector3D()
    {
    }
    public Vector3D(T a, T b, T c)
    {
        x = a; y = b; z = c;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //return base.ToString();
        return String.Format("({0} {1} {2})", x , y , z);
    }
    public Vector3D<double> operator+( Vector3D<double> right)
    {
        Vector3D<double> vd = new Vector3D<double>() { x = 0, y = 0, z = 0};
        vd.x = left.x + right.x;
        vd.y = left.y + right.y;
        vd.z = left.z + right.z;
        return vd;
    }
}
```

The error which you have is in operator+, because the containing type is `Exp<T>`, not `Exp<double>`. You should change it. Also there is no definition of left in this method !

Your method should like something like that:

```
    public static Vector3D<T> operator +(Vector3D<T> right)
    {

        Vector3D<T> vd = new Vector3D<T>();

        vd.x = right.x;
        vd.y = right.y;
        vd.z = right.z;
        return vd;
    }
```

Comment: why isnt "this" being used?

Comment: @user366866 You are trying to do template specialization(I think this is possible in C++) which is not directly possible in C#. I will asume that this is because C# generics aren't processed during the compilation and are more a feature of the runtime. They are some workarounds you can read it in net.

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot of extra work, you're not going to be able to implement a fully general-purpose generic `Vector3D<T>` class complete with mathematical operators. There are no constraints that you can provide for the generic type that will at once allow `T` to be a built-in numeric type and at the same time provide math operators for `T`.

There are a variety of ways to deal with this, such as special-casing the type in the generic class (yuck!), requiring `T` to implement an interface (i.e. wrap a normal numeric type in a type that implements the interface), or making the type abstract and requiring specialized subclasses to implement the operators as named methods (one of which could even depend on an interface, while others based directly on numeric types would just implement them directly).

For example:

```
abstract class Vector3D<T>
{
    public readonly T x;
    public readonly T y;
    public readonly T z;

    public Vector3D() { }
    public Vector3D(T x, T y, T z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public abstract Vector3D<T> Add(Vector3D<T> right);
}

class Vector3DDouble : Vector3D<double>
{
    public Vector3DDouble() { }
    public Vector3DDouble(double x, double y, double z)
        : base(x, y, z)
    { }

    public override Vector3D<double> Add(Vector3D<double> right)
    {
        return new Vector3DDouble(x + right.x, y + right.y, z + right.z);
    }
}
```

Assuming for the moment you've somehow addressed that issue, let's look at your `operator +` overload. First, your code won't even compile. You have overloaded the unary + operator, because you only have one parameter `right` for the overload, but in the method body you assume a second parameter `left` which is undeclared.

A more sensible implementation might look like this:

```
    public static Vector3D<T> operator+(Vector3D<T> left, Vector3D<T> right)
    {
        return left.Add(right);
    }
```

Note: I'm assuming here you've solved the arithmetic issue by requiring implementers to provide the arithmetic operations via named method, e.g. `Add()` per my example above. Obviously the exact implementation here would depend on how you dealt with the general issue of doing math with `T` values.